# How to implement data transfer from firebase to Data Fusion

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, service-accounts, google-cloud-data-fusion, fusion

I am looking for a way to automate data extraction from firebase to cloud data fusion. Firestore plugin available in data fusion hub is in preview mode, so not sure if that is reliable to use for now. Also, I am looking to get incremental data after first load such that pipeline only takes recent or new document created in firestore collection.

Answer (score 0):

plugin in hub can be patched very quickly , I would suggest you using it and send questions to https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/cdap-user if you find any bug, once the bug is fixed it can be quickly released to hub.